# django {% static "admin/" %}' producing 'admin' with missing trailing slash in production ONLY

Tags: django

Ok very weird issue here.

In the base.html file for the admin site they have this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">window.__admin_media_prefix__ = "{% filter escapejs %}{% static "admin/" %}{% endfilter %}";</script>
```

The important part is this `{% static "admin/" %}`. Its only used for a handful of things in javascript, one of them being the calendar icon url for the date widget.

Locally this works just fine, and the url ends up being `/static/admin/`. However on production, it ends up as `http://myaws.s3.address/admin` with no trailing slash.

I can't figure out for the life of me how this might happen. This is Django 1.4. My `STATIC_URL` for aws ends with a trailing slash. This has got to be in the staticfiles app somewhere right? I'm not sure how to track this one down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GAH!

Found the problem. Its a bug in django storages (s3 specifically):

http://code.larlet.fr/django-storages/issue/121/s3boto-admin-prefix-issue-with-django-14

Comment: Yup my mistake. I didn't know it had anything to do with the problem. Also, it doesn't seem like it's being very well maintained anymore. Lots of pulls and bugs that are months old.